# How to get real time value of a stock or security?

Tags: web-crawler, finance

How can I get real time values of some security, say stock or forex? It'd best be at least as accurate as per-second value. I want to try to develop a autonomous financial program making money for me through stock or forex investment. But I don't know where to get the real time data.

In particular, I need the following data regarding to some kind of stock or forex:

1. Value history, at least per second. (To train the program.)
2. Real time value, at least per second. (To operate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Using Alphavantage, It's free too
https://www.alphavantage.co/

Kindly Check this Question, Same as yours : 
https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-free-realtime-REST-APIs-for-getting-NASDAQ-DOW-stock-quotes

Comment: But their data is provided as real time value, however I need values measured in seconds.